# Searchkick search based on user saved recipes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

Working on some search queries using searchkick and having trouble figuring out how to set up the searchkick search to get the results i want.  So users can save recipes and recipes have tags associated with them.  I want to get all the tags from their saved recipes and search for recipes with the same tags and weight the tags based on how many times they appear.

So to get the tags I can do this:

```
tags = Tagging.where(taggable_id: current_user.saved_recipes.pluck(:recipe_id)).group(:tag_id).count
```

This returns something like this:

```
{23=>1, 56=>1, 27=>2, 30=>1, 28=>1, 36=>1, 39=>1, 16=>1}
```

Im just not sure how to pass that array to weight the numbers, so in that case tag 27 would have a higher weight then the rest.  The field Im searching against in my elasticsearch index is :tags.

```
Recipe.search "*", where: [tags: tag]
```

This was what I was thinking but the hash of tags has those numbers and not sure how to make that boost the results.  Hope this is clear

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the [`boost_where`](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#boosting) option, which allows you to boost results by a different factor for different values.

Specifically, in your case, you could try:

```rb
tags = Tagging.where(taggable_id: current_user.saved_recipes.pluck(:recipe_id)).group(:tag_id).count

# Boost any tags with count greater than 1
boost_values = tags.select { |k, v| v > 1 }.map { |k,v| {value: k, factor: v * 10} }

Recipe.search "*", where: [tags: tag], boost_where: {tags: boost_values}
```

Comment: That got me most of the way there.  Will need to adjust it some to weight it the way I want.  But that will be thru testing.  Thanks